# Instance variable hiding with inheritance

Tags: java, inheritance

In the code below, the instance variable called "x" inside subclass "B" hides the instance variable also called "x" inside the parent superclass "A".

```
public class A {
    public int x;
}

public class B extends A {
    public int x;
}
```

In the code below, why does println(z.x) display the value of zero?  Thanks.

```
A a = new A();
B b = new B();

a.x = 1;
b.x = 2;

A z = b;
System.out.println(z.x);  // Prints 0, but why?
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> In the code below, why does println(z.x) display the value of zero?

Because it's referring to the `x` field declared in `A`... that's the only one that `z.x` *can* refer to, because the compile-time type of `z` is `A`.

The instance of `B` you've created has two fields: the one declared in `A` (which has the value 0) and the one declared in `B` (which has the value 2). The instance of `A` you created is entirely irrelevant; it's a completely independent object.

This is good reason to:

- Make all of your fields private, drastically reducing the possibility of hiding one field with another
- Avoid hiding even where it's possible, as it causes confusion

Comment: So if you were to set x in the superclass by passing the value trough the constructor, which the constructor passes it to the super class's constructor `public B(int x) { super(x); }`. Would the value then be different when initializing `z` and calling `z.x`?

Comment: @VinceEmigh: Well that would rely on the `A` constructor setting it too... and introducing a *parameter* called `x` as well makes things even more confusing. I suggest you just try it, to be honest.

Comment: Yeah, in class A: `public int x;` `public A(int i) { x = i; }`. I'm not on a computer right now, but I'll test it right when I get on one. It just seems like it would work as long as you set `int x' in the superclass aswell

Comment: @Vince: Yes, but they'll still be two independent variables which happen to start with the same value.